# How to extract array<bigint> in hive table in spark properly?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table which has a column(c4) with `array<bigint>` type. Now, I want to extract this column with spark. So, here is the code snippet:

```
val query = """select c1, c2, c3, c4 from 
               some_table where some_condition"""
val rddHive = hiveContext.sql(query).rdd.map{ row =>

//is there any other ways to extract wid_list(String here seems not work)
//no compile error and no runtime error
val w = if (row.isNullAt(3)) List() else row.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("wid_list").toList
w
}
-> rddHive: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:32

rddHive.map(x => x(0).getClass.getSimpleName).take(1)
-> Array[String] = Array[Long]
```

So, I extract c4 with `getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]`, while the original data type is `array<int>`. However, there is no compile error or runtime error. Data I extracted is still bigint(Long) type. So, what happened here(why no compiler error or runtime error)? What is the proper way to extract `array<int>` as `List[String]`in Spark?

==================add more information====================

```
hiveContext.sql(query).printSchema
root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

hiveContext.sql(query).show(3)
+--------+----+----------------+--------------------+
|      c1|  c2|              c3|                  c4|
+--------+----+----------------+--------------------+
|   c1111|   1|5511798399.22222|[21772244666, 111...|
|   c1112|   1|5511798399.88888|[11111111, 111111...|
|   c1113|   2| 5555117114.3333|[77777777777, 112...|
```

Comment: A compile-time error cannot occur because the dataframe schema is only known at runtime. Have you tried to call collect on `rddHive`? I get a runtime-exception in this case.

Comment: Yes, I have tried take(1). And I get Array[List[String]] = Array(List(...)), no run time error.

Comment: Can you help **me** a bit and edit your question with the output of `query.show` and `query.printSchema`? That'd be very helpful to help you.